# Get selected file's path asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i can't find anywhere how can i get selected file's path in asp.net mvc (i am using c#)?
I need to send file to server, so i just need to get it's path and then i use

```
             Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
```

but only way to get path i found was:

```
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
```

but i dont want to save my file. If i use

```
Path.GetFullPath
```

i get path in II Express folder and i can not use this path.
So, is there any way to get selected file's path?

How  select file:

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
<input type=file id=File1 name=file value="Browse"  runat="server" dir="rtl" aria-selected="false" />
<br>
<input type="submit" id="Submit1" value="Upload" runat="server" aria-haspopup="False" dir="rtl" />
```

Comment: If you don't want to save the file, try using the raw stream with `Image.FromStream` instead.

Comment: You cannot access the File system of a client if that's what you mean. That would be a security breach.

Comment: Okay,now i understand that it was kind of stupid, to expect to get information about users files. So using Image.FromStream would help me toget what i want, but now i dont know how to convert my HttpPostedFileBase file to steam.:/

Comment: Okay,now i get what i want!!
I just used 
      var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);

tanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to get the file's path on the client, and "read" it to an image object - that's impossible, because the server doesn't have access to the client's filesystem.

Normally, a file upload will look like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
    <input id="File1" type="file" runat="server" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="Btn1_ServerClick" />
</div>
</form>
```

and the server side is:

```
protected void Btn1_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = File1.PostedFile;
    var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
}
```

This is in classic ASP.NET, but if you're using MVC.NET and accessing a controller action it's pretty similar (the controller will receive some sort of `HttpPostedFileBase` as a parameter from the form)

Answer (score 0):

It is proper behavior of the server and framework that you receive path to location on server.
Normally when we mean one way communication from client to server, as it occurs with http requests (e.g. get or post), the server has not access to clients' file system (hard disk etc). Normally uploading data to server   (file) by choosing file on client's file system is sending the data (copy of the file), not path to the file. Server does not initiate getting the file form client by using client's path to it.